# Javascript - Restructure the array of objects

Tags: javascript

I currently have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[{day:"Monday", Country:"America", cases:200},
{day:"Monday", Country:"India", cases:120},
{day:"Monday", Country:"Germany", cases:20},
{day:"Tuesday", Country:"America", cases:210},
{day:"Tuesday", Country:"India", cases:110},
{day:"Tuesday", Country:"Germany", cases:35},
{day:"Wednesday", Country:"America", cases:250},
{day:"Wednesday", Country:"India", cases:150},
{day:"Wednesday", Country:"Germany", cases:50}]
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to restructure this data to look like this:

```
[{day:"Monday", "America":200, "India":120, "Germany":20},    
 {day:"Tuesday", "America":210, "India":110, "Germany":35},    
 {day:"Wednesday", "America":250, "India":150, "Germany":50}]
```

Can anyone provide some advice for this and any good resources for restructuring javascript objects?

Answer (score 1):

We can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create a summary of cases by day, and then by country.

We start by creating a map of cases, keyed on `day`, then we use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to turn this map into an array.

I would suggest whenever you wish to restructure Arrays in general, have a look at
[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map),
[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter), and [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), these are all powerful methods for changing Array structure.

```js
const arr = [{day:"Monday", Country:"America", cases:200}, {day:"Monday", Country:"India", cases:120}, {day:"Monday", Country:"Germany", cases:20}, {day:"Tuesday", Country:"America", cases:210}, {day:"Tuesday", Country:"India", cases:110}, {day:"Tuesday", Country:"Germany", cases:35}, {day:"Wednesday", Country:"America", cases:250}, {day:"Wednesday", Country:"India", cases:150}, {day:"Wednesday", Country:"Germany", cases:50}];

const result = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    // Create the summary for the day if it doesn't exist
    acc[cur.day] = acc[cur.day] || { day: cur.day};
    // Create the summary for the country if it doesn't exist and add the cases in cur
    acc[cur.day][cur.Country] = (acc[cur.day][cur.Country] || 0) + cur.cases;
    return acc;
}, {}))

console.log('Result:',result)
```

Comment: Thank you so much and for the suggestion. I was struck with the map itself and did not have much hands-on with reduce(). Your solution snippet really inspired me to learn more.

Comment: Map, Filter and Reduce are very useful, not just in JavaScript but many other languages too. Of course there are other techniques for manipulating arrays / lists etc, but mastering these will be a very good idea for any developer. Good luck with your project!